# Sum function of an infinite series involving power function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, power-series

I'm trying to find an explicit expression for the following function serie:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$,$0<x<1$.

It's easy to prove that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}$

and

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$.

It is more than amazing that when we expand the power function $x^n$ by the Taylor series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$

$=(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n+\cdots)+(x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots+x^{2n+2}+\cdots)+(x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots+x^{3n+3}+\cdots)+\cdots$

$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tau(n)x^n$,

where $\tau(n)$ represents the number of factors of $n$.But yet this maynot help to solve the question.

while trying to solve it by numerical methods, I find that $\frac{x}{(1-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ fits the sum function well.

[image: enter image]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233847/42969

Comment: Thank you for the answer and yet I still want to know whether an analytical solution exists.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "an analytical solution". It's unlikely that there is a closed form for the sum.

Comment: Sorry for making a mistake...yeah,I mean I need a closed form and I have got it.Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum has the following closed form (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BDivisorSigma%5B0%2C%20n%5D%20x%5En%2C%20%7Bn%2C%201%2C%20%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D)) where $\psi_x^{(0)}(1)$ is the [q-Polygamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).

---

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\sigma_0(n) x^n\right)=\frac{\psi _x^{(0)}(1)+\log (1-x)}{\log (x)}\tag{1}$$

---

The following plot illustrates the left side of formula (1) evaluated at $N=100$ in orange overlaid on the closed form representation on the right side of formula (1) in blue.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of left side of formula (1) (orange) overlaid on right side of formula (1) (blue)